# secure url not working with nginx+node

Tags: node.js, express, nginx

I have a mean stack application which is served via nginx proxy.

nginx settings are as below:

```
server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.example.com;
  ssl_certificate /home/deploy/www.example.com.chained.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /home/deploy/example.com.key;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
  }
}
```

The express add is setup as below:

```
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(8080);
```

When I access the website via secure URL
https://www.example.com

I recieve the following page:

"Moved Temporarily. Redirecting to http://127.0.0.1"
or
just a blank page

Answer (score 0):

The URL `http://127.0.0.1` is not being rewritten to `https://www.example.com`. The default should be equivalent to:

```
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1:8080/ /;
```

The default is not being actioned. Maybe because the `proxy_path` directive does not include a trailing `/` or maybe because the application is not specifying a port in its redirect header.

You could try the following:

```
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
proxy_redirect default;
proxy_redirect http://127.0.0.1/ /;
```